# Find duplicate values in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I know how to do this in T-SQL - it's easy.

How can I do this in EF using C# ?

```
SELECT
    name, email, COUNT(*)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    name, email
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

What is the Entity Framework equivalent to this?

The question that is marked as a duplicate **is not an answer** to this question. Maybe the person who marked it as a duplicate doesn't understand EF or T-SQL.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question. Question is not a duplicate

Comment: Should be something like `users.GroupBy( u => new { u.Name, u.Email } ).Where( g => g.Count() > 1 ).Select( g => new { Name = g.Key.Name, Email = g.Key.Email, Count = g.Count() )`. Report back if this works.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question? It's almost identical! If that's not a duplicate all duplicates at Stack Overflow are false.

Comment: You just said "It's *almost* identical".......

Comment: The duplicate does not answer my question... Please don't mark as duplicate unless you actually understand the questions. Thanks.

Comment: The duplicate is asking how to do a EF equivalent with a JOIN. I'm not talking about a join NOR am i looking for LINQ-QUERY syntax...

Comment: @WiktorZychla  I am trying your solution now, thanks.

Comment: @WiktorZychla It worked. Thanks

Comment: The duplicate asks "How can I write a linq to entities query that includes a having clause?". The join is a minor difference. You should be able to tune out such small differences and focus on the essentials when searching for answers on the web. You can't expect a question like this not to have been asked before and you should have been able to find the answer without posting a new question.